# bootstrap dialog esc key not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

this is my dialog, but esc key is not working, do you have any ideas what might be wrong ?

```
<div *ngIf="visible" class="overlay">
    <div role="dialog" class="overlay-content" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog" [ngClass]="{'wide-modal-dialog': wideContent}" >
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" *ngIf="header.length > 0">
                    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{ header }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ng-content></ng-content>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer footer-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="positiveDisabled" (click)="confirm()">{{ positiveBtnLabel }}</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="close()">{{ negativeBtnLabel }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you consider trying out https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples ?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource that requries me to download additionall packages and rebuild totally dialog, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why it doesn't work, but you can set a listener in a directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[onEsc]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    onEsc = new EventEmitter<Event>();

    @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            this.onEsc.emit(event);
        }
    }
}
```

and in the component:

```
.... (onEsc)=close()....
```